# React Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') altought it shouldnt be undefined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have list of countries, and i want to create grid, with items being the countries. I have 2 grids, first grid shows just the first country, the second grid  shows the rest of them.

However the first grid complains about the object being undefined. Sometimes this code works but usually i get the error about not Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name'). Why is this happening? And why does the second grid does not complain? ( I even staticly declared the list of countries here, so its not like im waiting for some service to return the data)

```
const Countries = () => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
    const tooltip = useRef(null);

    const tmpCountries = [{
        name: "country"
    }, {
        name: "country2"
    }, {
        name: "country3"
    }, {
        name: "country4"
    }, {
        name: "country5"
    }, {
        name: "country6"
    }, {
        name: "country7"
    }, {
        name: "country8"
    }, {
        name: "country9"
    }, {
        name: "country10"
    }, {
        name: "country11"
    }, {
        name: "country12"
    }, {
        name: "country13"
    }, {
        name: "country"
    }, {
        name: "country2"
    }, {
        name: "country3"
    }, {
        name: "country4"
    }, {
        name: "country5"
    }, {
        name: "country6"
    }, {
        name: "country7"
    }, {
        name: "country8"
    }, {
        name: "country9"
    }, {
        name: "country10"
    }, {
        name: "country11"
    }, {
        name: "country12"
    }, {
        name: "country13"
    }]

 useEffect(() => {
        const countries = tmpCountries;
        setCountries(countries);
    }, [])

   return (
        <div className="countriesHolder">
            <Typography variant="h3" component="h3">
                List of countries.
            </Typography>

            <div className="countries">
                <Grid container
                      direction="row"
                      rowSpacing={1}
                      spacing={{xs: 2, md: 3}} columns={{xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12}}
                      alignItems="center"
                      justifyContent="center"
                >
                    <Grid item xs={4} sm={6} md={6} mt={5}>
                        {console.log(countries[0])}
                        <Item className="item">{countries[0].name}</Item>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

                <Grid container
                      direction="row"
                      rowSpacing={1}
                      spacing={{xs: 2, md: 3}} columns={{xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12}}
                      alignItems="center"
                      justifyContent="center"
                >
                    {
                        countries.map((country, i) => {
                            if (i == 0) return;
                            return <Grid item xs={4} sm={6} md={6} mt={5}>
                                <Item className="item">{country.name}</Item>
                            </Grid>
                        })
                    }
                </Grid>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

is there some react bug im too green to notice?
THanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the countries state with tmpCountries:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState(tmpCountries)
```

You are trying to retrieve `countries[0]` on component render which is fist referencing the empty array; therefore, giving you an `undefined` value.

If you want to get the country list asynchronously through an API fetch, then you can change the render function to only show once the counties array is populated:

```
return (
   {
     countries.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="countriesHolder">
            <Typography variant="h3" component="h3">
                List of countries.
            </Typography>

            ...
        </div>
     ) : (
        <p>Loading...</p>
     )
    )
```

Comment: and what about the case when i will load the data from some service? And wonr have them statically typed

Comment: @Johnyb updated answer for API fetch

Answer (score 0):

When your component renders for the first time countries is still an empty list since the effect runs right after rendering. You try to access the first element with `countries[0]` but it doesn't exist yet so you get `undefined` and then try to access `.name` which doesn't work. Add optional chaining like so `countries[0]?.name`

Comment: and what about the case when i will load the data from some service?

Comment: @Johnyb `countries?.length > 0 ? countries[0].name : 'loading...'`